# Variance of random variables (density)

Tags: probability-distributions, variance, change-of-variable

Random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have density $f_x(x)$ and $f_y(x)$:

$f_x(x)=4x^2e^{-2x}\mathbb{1}_{x>0}$

$f_y(x)=\frac{8}{3}x^3e^{-2x}\mathbb{1}_{x>0}$.

Calculate $Var(\frac{X}{X+Y})$
I tried to find density for $\frac{X}{X+Y}$, but from changing of variables I have $T(X,Y)=(\frac{X}{X+Y},Y)$. Jacobian of $T^{-1}(X,Y)$ is complicated and maybe someone can do it easier?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take $X+Y$ as the second variable instead of $Y$ in the change of variables.

Comment: Yes, it is good, thank you!